# How do I replace an old copy of my gDoc (google sheet) with the new one without messing up the link?

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api

I was told that simply dragging and dropping the new file into the folder should overwrite the old copy, this wasn't true. Nor is there "manage file version" or similar within the drive interface right click. (I've seen old screenshots where it appears in the same context menu  with download, share, etc). Within the sheet itself I can see the different versions but there is nowhere to upload a new version.

The folder is a team drive but it doesn't seem to work in my personal folders either.

Comment: Your questions was answered in this [SE post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/30512/google-drive-permalink-that-doesnt-change-with-new-file-versions). Basically, when you are uploading a new file, it will generate the new shareable link and if you upload a revision it will remain the same.

Comment: Sadly I do NOT have "manage revisions" in any of the dropdown menus. And as it is a google sheet there isn't a straight up upload point, dragging it intothe folder doesn't seemto work exactly the same way